# Merge sort algorithm compilation error [HELP]

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void print(int a[], int sz) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) cout << a[i] << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
} 

void merge(int a[], const int low, const int mid, const int high) 
{
    int *temp = new int[high-low+1];

    int left = low;
    int right = mid+1;
    int current = 0;
    // Merges the two arrays into temp[]
    while(left <= mid && right <= high)
    {
        if(a[left] <= a[right])
        {
            temp[current] = a[left];
            left++;
        }
        else { // if right element is smaller that the left
        {
            // if right element is smaller that the left
            temp[current] = a[right];
            right++;
        }
        current++;
    }

    // Fills the array

    // The temp array has already been filled
    // Use the right side of array to fill temp
    if(left > mid)
    {
        for(int i=right; i <= high;i++)
        {
            temp[current] = a[i];
            current++;
        }
    }

    // Use the left side of array to fill temp
    else
    {
        for(int i=left; i <= mid; i++)
        {
            temp[current] = a[i];
            current++;
        }
    }

    //Fill into original array
    for(int i=0; i<=high-low;i++)
    {
        a[i+low] = temp[i];
    }
    delete[] temp;
}

void merge_sort(int a[], const int low, const int high)
{ // <-- Error #68
    if(low >= high) return;
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    merge_sort(a, low, mid); //left half
    merge_sort(a, mid+1, high); //right half
    merge(a, low, mid, high); //merge them
}

int main()
{ //<-- Error #77
    int a[] = {26, 5, 33, 6, 19, 69, 99};

    int arraySize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    print(a, arraySize);
    merge_sort(a, 0, (arraySize-1));
    print(a, arraySize);

    return 0;
} //<-- Error #87
```

// This code is supposed to implement the Merge sort algorithm in c++.
However when ever i compile my code it runs into a bunch of errors.

> mergesort.cpp: In function ‘void merge(int*, int, int, int)’:
>   mergesort.cpp:68: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
>   mergesort.cpp:77: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
>   mergesort.cpp:87: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

I have indicated where the erros are in the code
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You have `else { // if right ...` and then another `{` on the next line you probably meant to just do `else // if right...`.

Comment: Wow.. rookie mistake.Thanks bro, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void print(int a[], int sz) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) cout << a[i] << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
} 

void merge(int a[], const int low, const int mid, const int high) 
{
    int *temp = new int[high-low+1];

    int left = low;
    int right = mid+1;
    int current = 0;
    // Merges the two arrays into temp[]
    while(left <= mid && right <= high)
    {
        if(a[left] <= a[right])
        {
            temp[current] = a[left];
            left++;
        }
        else 
        { 

            // if right element is smaller that the left
            temp[current] = a[right];
            right++;
        }
        current++;
    }

    // Fills the array

    // The temp array has already been filled
    // Use the right side of array to fill temp
    if(left > mid)
    {
        for(int i=right; i <= high;i++)
        {
            temp[current] = a[i];
            current++;
        }
    }

    // Use the left side of array to fill temp
    else
    {
        for(int i=left; i <= mid; i++)
        {
            temp[current] = a[i];
            current++;
        }
    }

    //Fill into original array
    for(int i=0; i<=high-low;i++)
    {
        a[i+low] = temp[i];
    }
    delete[] temp;
}

void merge_sort(int a[], const int low, const int high)
{
    if(low >= high) return;
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    merge_sort(a, low, mid); //left half
    merge_sort(a, mid+1, high); //right half
    merge(a, low, mid, high); //merge them
}

main()
{
    int a[] = {26, 5, 33, 6, 19, 69, 99};

    int arraySize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    print(a, arraySize);
    merge_sort(a, 0, (arraySize-1));
    print(a, arraySize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you write an extra `{` on line 27, which will mess up all those `{` `}` matching.

Delete that you will pass the compile.

Hope this helps.